# JQuery event saving user's input

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events, controls, focusout

I am trying to save a user's input once they have clicked on another control on the page. I had a look at the focusout event but it fires every time user enters value or selects another control. here is how i used it:

```
        $('#txt_ComplainingAbout').focusout(function (e) {
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Form.aspx/Save",
                    data: "{'id': '" + this.value + "','value': '" + this.value + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg.d == 'success') {

                        }
                    }

                });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Is there any other way to call the above ajax call per control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the `blur` event not give you the behavior you want?

Also, have you looked at a delegated event? With a delegated approach you use a single event handler to deal with events raised by multiple elements. So if you had a table with 10,000 cells, and you wanted to perform some action on click, instead of attaching an event handler to every one - which would be costly for performance - we attach one event handler to the table which is delegated to handle all events.

So following this paradigm, you could always have a single event handler for a form which handles every input in that form.

```
$("form").on("blur", ":input", function(e) {
    // this refers to whichever form element triggered the event
    var $this;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Form.aspx/Save",
        data: "{'id': '" + $this.attr("id") + "','value': '" + $this.val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d == 'success') {

            }
        }

    });

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaining .... so if I have one event as per your example would any text input field be firing $.ajax when it is out of focus? also how about dropdowns controls do I need another event?

Comment: also trying your example and i get on is not a function error(am using jquery 1.5.1

Comment: Correct, this will handle all inputs. Better yet, because we're using the jQuery custom selector `:input` this will also select textareas, selects, checkbox etc. I'm not sure whether `blur` fires for selects, radio buttons and all type of form input, so this will require some investigation by you, but this should definitely be enough to get you going

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was introduced as the standard event handler syntax in 1.7. If you're stuck on an earlier version, investigate [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead. Works the same, but the method signature is slightly different (if i remember rightly the first two params are swapped around) so look it up

Comment: sure will have a look but for now to test updated to 1.8.3....the only issue i see here is once i change focus from one control to another the event fires twice...is there any way to prevent this...I think it happens once for the control i am changing and once for new control...

Comment: If you whip up a fiddle, i will happily help. Blur *should* only fire when a form element loses focus, but there may be edge cases.

Comment: sorry if it sounds dumb bt how do I run fiddle?

Comment: No questions are dumb! Visit http://www.jsfiddle.net and start typing code ;-) Replace the ajax calls with console logs or something so we can see values coming through the events

Comment: Thank you. tried it http://jsfiddle.net/sam1/LVwnQ/ and it works fine, i get only one alert..but on my local i get it twice..

Comment: the only difference is i am using asp:Texbox

Comment: if it helps i keep on getting this error
Error: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMWindow.alert]

Comment: I think NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE is to do with cross domain AJAX? Are you getting two events because you left your previous code in place?

Comment: got it working instead of delegate looking for form i used document.body and is firing once now. thanks a lot for your help really appreciate it

Comment: be careful of adding delegates to the body as it can cause performance hits. For example if you put a hover delegate on the body, *every time you hovered over anything*, the event bubbles all the way to the body, where the source element must be inspected to check for a match to your selector. You should apply delegates as locally as possible. If form is giving you problems (is this because you're nesting forms, i notice you're using ASP.net. nesting forms is invalid and will defo cause issues), try the attaching to the next container/div up the DOM

Comment: Oh and please consider marking as answer if this solved your issue (or any other answer, just one of them!)

Comment: Yes it is nested forms and I am using JQuery Tabs so that is why it run it twice i think. I have a div after form and i have attached it to that :).. I have marked it as answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
 $('#txt_ComplainingAbout').unbind('focusout').bind('focusout', function (e) {

    //your code
    return false; //to prevent the browser actually following the links!

});
```

**EXPLANATION**

`focusout(function() {}` method is a shortcut for `.bind('focusout', handler)`.

For more information check [**.focusout()**](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

By using above way (`unbind/bind`) you can sort it out issues like when click button once it fires 2 times or the issue your having kind of.

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Are we sure this will actually work? There's no explanation as to what this is actually doing, or how it remedies the issue. Drive-by answers like this aren't helpful or constructive

Comment: @Sam1 did you try this or what ? just try and let me know.Then I will explain the scenario .

Comment: @Sam1 I have updated my post plz check and let me know if it's not enough?